# How can you find a basis for subspace of linear maps that preserve some algebraic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, tensors

### Background

I am trying to learn about relativity. One way to define the Poincaré Group is that its elements commute with the spacetime metric. The spacetime metric is an example of inner product, but could also be viewed as an algebraic form. I'm interested in how this concept generalizes to other algebraic forms.

### Question

Suppose that you have some vector space $V$ along with an algebraic form (in [tensor notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation))

$$\mathbf{\Phi x} = A + B_{\mu}x^\mu + C_{\mu \nu}x^\mu x^\nu + D_{\mu \nu \gamma}x^\mu x^\nu x^\gamma + ...$$

Suppose also that have a family $\Lambda^\mu_\nu \in \bf\Lambda$ of linear automorphisms of $V$ that preserves $\mathbf{\Phi}$, i.e. for which

$$\mathbf{\Phi} \Lambda^\mu_\nu = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \mathbf{\Phi}$$

How can you find a basis for $\bf\Lambda$ in terms of the of $A$, $B_\mu$, $C_{\mu \nu}$, etc?

### Thoughts

We can view $\bf \Lambda$ as a subspace of $V^*$, the dual space of $V$. My intuition tells me there should be some "$\mathbf{\Phi}^*$" defined on $V^*$ and that the algebraic expression of this $\mathbf{\Phi}^*$ would be homomorphic to the algebraic form of $\mathbf{\Phi}$ in $V$. I.e., something like "if $C$ is anti-symmetric, then $C^*$ is symmetric".

### Update

I think the formulation of question has some conceptual errors. The key property of the Poincaré Group is that it preserves a certain relationship between two points in Minkowski space. So there are actually two generalizations:

1. Increase the number of points under consideration. Then $\mathbf{x}$ would be more aptly interpreted as a collection of vectors
2. Generalize the relationship to some function of the coordinates of both points rather than a quadratic equation like the Minkowski metric

I think I somewhat mashed the two up in the original question.

Comment: Is $\Phi$ is a map $V \rightarrow V$?  What kind of thing 
 are $\mu, \nu$ etc., and what does $x^\mu$ mean for a vector $x$?

Comment: I added a note stating the the equations are expressed using Einstein notation

Comment: The range of $\Phi$ would be whichever field $V$ is over. So if $V$ is the cartesian product of some number of copies of $K$, then $\mathbf{\Phi}: V \rightarrow K$

Comment: The equation $\Phi\Lambda_\nu^\mu = \Lambda_\nu^\mu\Phi$ doesn't make any sense. I take it you mean $\Phi( \Lambda(x)) = \Phi(x)$ for all $x$, ie $\Phi$ doesn't change under the action of $\Lambda$. This is also what the equation Lorentz group  elements must satisfy where $\Phi$ is the Minkowski quadratic form.

Comment: What is the space of automorphisms that leave $\Phi$ invariant? By comparing coefficients you find that $B_\mu\Lambda_\nu^\mu = B_\nu$, that $C_{\mu\nu}\Lambda^\mu_\alpha \Lambda^\nu_\beta = C_{\alpha\beta}$, that $D_{\mu\nu\rho} \Lambda^\mu_\alpha \Lambda^\nu_\beta \Lambda^\rho_\gamma = D_{\alpha\beta\gamma} $ and so on. The first condition means that $B^T$ must be an eigenvector of eigenvalue $1$ of $\Lambda^T$. The higher order terms do not admit so easy characterisations. You can describe the Lie algebra of the group more simply though.